# Delayed Baggage Compensation Turkish Airlines

Tags: compensation, turkish-airlines, lost-luggage

I was recently on a trip and my baggage was delivered late (to the tune of 46 days after my arrival).

I filed a delayed baggage report via Turkish Airlines' online form. The updates were excruciatingly slow, but we have reached a point where the airline has requested for receipts of goods I purchased during the days I lost my bag. The airline has acknowledged that my file has been evaluated already and is now with their claims departments.

My question is: is it a reasonable expectation that the airline will compensate me? It has been so long since I received the acknowledgement (about 25 days already) and I still haven't received any news about compensation. What is the usual timeline for this?